# SVG animation not working on firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, svg, gsap

I am trying to use this animation

http://codepen.io/dbj/full/epXEyd

```
var tl = new TimelineLite;
tl.staggerFromTo(".bottom", 0.8, {alpha: 0}, {alpha: 1, fill: "#d6d6d6", delay: 1}, 0.25)
tl.fromTo("#rectangle", 5, {fill:"#d6d6d6", alpha: "0%", height: "7%"}, {fill: "#c8db2d", alpha: "100%", height: "65%", ease: Power3.easeInOut}, "-=1")
tl.staggerFromTo(".ray", 1, {alpha: 0}, {alpha: 1, fill: "#cee325"}, 0.02, "-=1.25")
```

in a website but it doesn't seem fully compatible with Firefox browser (on chrome it works perfectly), is there any way I can make it work for all browsers?

I tried to change the javascript calls to the animation libraries, using `from` instead of `fromTo` etc, everything works fine in chrome but not in firefox. (or if someone know other similar animation i could use it would be nice too :D).
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to guess, I'd say it is an issue with the animation library you are using.

In the animation, it is attempting to animate the height of a `<rect>` element to give that rising fill effect.  Note the height 7%->66% transition in the code below.

```
.fromTo("#rectangle", 7, {fill:"#000", alpha: "0%", height: "7%"}, {fill: "#f5e317", alpha: "100%", height: "66%", ease: Power3.easeInOut}, "-=1")
```

The height of the rectangle is not actually changing while the animation is running. So I suspect it may be a bug or incompatibility in the way the animation library is setting the height during the animation.

Cut down demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Vjadwm

If you get no answers here, I would consider asking Greensock for help, or posting a bug report with them.

Comment: rect height is not a CSS property in SVG 1.1, it's an attribute (and in this case Firefox supports SVG 1.1 only) rect height is proposed to be a CSS property in SVG 2 (and in this case Chrome supports SVG 2). SVG 2 is unfinished and Firefox will likely in time support this feature as it does some other SVG 2 features that Chrome does not yet support. GSAPI should be clever enough to hide this issue really.

Comment: @Robert, I haven't used Greensock, so didn't want to assume in my answer that it only animated CSS properties. But I probably should have included that info.

Comment: I think it does animate attributes in some cases. Presumably it's just some oversight in this particular API, as the OP says from animation works.